# Mouseover changes text inside separate DIV

Tags: javascript, html, mouse

Is it possible to change the text inside a separate div from a mouseover over a separate link?  Would anyone know where to direct me or show me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes a simple javascript to do this

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function changeContent()
    {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML='New Content';
    }
  </SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
  <div id="myDiv">
    Old Content
  </div>
  <a href="#" onmouseover="changeContent()">Change Div Content</a>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: How would I handle multiple mouseovers for the same content DIV?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by multiple mouseovers. In case, you mean reverting back to old text when mouse moves out, it has been dealt with in lower answers better. It is better to use jquery or any other javascript framework so that you do not have to deal with browser quirks

Answer (score 2):

Here an small example with [jquery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $(".pass").hover(
      function () {
         $(".change").text("MOUSE HOVER");
        },
        function () {
         $(".change").text("DIV TO CHANGE");
        }
        );
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="pass">PASS YOUR MOUSE OVER HERE</div>
<div class="change">DIV TO CHANGE</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would you add multiple mouseovers with different corresponding texts?

Comment: what you mean about multiple mouseovers?! you can see in the docs the function hover receives 2 callbacks, the first is when the mouser enter the second when the mouse leaves, so in first callback you can do whatever you want! take a look in the docs(http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Javascript library like [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)
for example:

```
$('#youranchorid').mouseover(function() {
  $('#yourdivid').html("Your new text");
});
```

[check the API](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

Comment: How would you make it fall back to the original text?

Comment: using the function .mouseleave() it has the same structure as .mousover(), you can also use .mousenter() instead of .mouseover()