# Change div content based on mouse hover on different divs

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

Hi this question is sort of building off of this previous question [mouse hover changes text inside separate DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920691/mouseover-changes-text-inside-separate-div) asked by someone else.

Only I believe the original poster was asking for multiple hovers and no one seemed to understand the request.. I believe I'm looking for what he was looking for so i'll try to explain it best a I can.

say I have a div

```
<div id="content">Descriptions should appear here</div>
```

and a list of links positioned anywhere else on the page with it's own descriptions (only the list is visible not the descriptions)

```
foo = bar and stuff
apples = a red fruit
keyboard = thing you type with
boat = floats on water
```

How would I make it so that if someone hovered over one of the links, the description would then be shown in the content div?

---

Thanks for all the replies! In the end, this is what I went with:

javascript:

```
<script>
    function changeContent(description) {
        console.log(description);
        var MyDesc = document.getElementById(description);
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = MyDesc.value;
    }
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="content"></div>

<a onmouseover="changeContent('desc1')" href="#">Apples</a>
  <input type="hidden" id="desc1" value="apples are delicious">
<a onmouseover="changeContent('desc2')" href="#">Oranges</a>
  <input type="hidden" id="desc2" value="Oranges are healthy">
<a onmouseover="changeContent('desc3')" href="#">Candy</a>
  <input type="hidden" id="desc3" value="Candy is tasty!">
```

having a separate input for the description leaves me the option to movie it around if need be. Thanks again for all the great answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this solution uses pure javascript.

```html
<div id="content">
    Stuff should be placed here.
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<ul>
    <li onmouseover="hover('Apples are delicious')">Apple</li>
    <li onmouseover="hover('oranges are healthy')">Orange</li>
    <li onmouseover="hover('Candy is the best')">Candy</li>
</ul>

<script>
    function hover(description) {
        console.log(description);
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = description;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is perfect, I can manipulate it quite easily for my links. Thanks soo much!

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you the simplest of answers and an example to show how easy this is:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Iko6KQIhWO)

Html:

```
<div id="content">
  This is some cool default content!
</div>

<div id="foo">Bar and stuff</div>
<div id="apples">A red fruit</div>
<div id="keyboard">Thing you type with</div>
<div id="boat">Floats on water</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#foo, #apples, #keyboard, #boat").hover(function(e){
  $("#content").text($(this).text());
});
```

There's a lot more you need to do to make this a viable/useable webpage, but this will point you in the right direction.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the onmouseover Event

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

And then have you script change the style of "content" to display inline, and then back to none when they leave the hover with onmouseout

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and register a hover event for every line in your list. In the event function you would be able to access the content of the hovered tag with $(this).text();

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/v6ay0yy6/ 
In my example on mouseout it will display the old div content also, you can remove that part if needed. Also instead of `hover` you could use jquery events like `mouseenter`, `mouseover` etc

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="clickable" data-desc="bar and stuff">Fo</li>
    <li class="clickable" data-desc="a red fruit">apples</li>
    <li class="clickable" data-desc="thing you type with">keyboard</li>
    <li class="clickable" data-desc="floats on water">boat</li>
</ul>
<div id="content">Descriptions should appear here</div>
```

Javascript(jQuery Required)

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function () {
    desc = $(this).attr('data-desc'); //get the description
    $('#content').text(desc);
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jcw6v7Le/