# Transformable div with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, dynamic-content

As the title suggest I am trying to code a transformable div with dynamic content. Basically I want the div's text to change on mouse hover. 
Below is the code I have, I never anticipate the ul to show the bullet points in the div before mouse hover.

**EDIT**
for clarification I want the div to have a default text i.e "word", then on hover it changes to "Word to your mother", then when the mouse is off the element, it will change back to "Word".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
    .wrap{
        margin: 30px auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
        width: 90vw;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .blue{
        background-color: rgba(56, 207, 248, 0.5);
    }

    .scale{
        transform: scale(1, 1);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease;
    }

    .box{
        width: calc(20%);
        margin: 20px 20px;
        background: #ddd;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 130px;
    }

    .box:hover .scale{
        transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    }

</style>

<head>
    <title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="blue scale">
                <ul id="content">
                    <li onmouseout="Default('word')"></li>
                    <li onmouseover="hover('Word to your mother')"></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>

<script>
        function hover(description) {
            console.log(description);
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = description;
        }

        function Default(description){
            console.log(description);
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = description;
        }

</script>
</html>
```

Below is the resources I had accessed in trying to solve this question.

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/text-change-on-div-hover/216212/2

https://codepen.io/vailjoy/pen/ZLLLYd

[Change div content based on mouse hover on different divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097666/change-div-content-based-on-mouse-hover-on-different-divs)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So what is the result you expect ? The text in div is changed when hover.

Comment: I edited my question to better reflect what I was looking for. The transformation is largely happening in the way I wanted it to, it just the dynamic changing of the text that isn't happening how I would like.

Answer (score 0):

If I have the following

```
<div class="changethis" data-descr=" to your mother" > Word </div>
```

My css would be

```
    .changethis:hover:after {

    content: attr(data-descr)
}
```

So before hover it would read "Word" then on hover it would read "Word to your mother" and then after moving cursor away it will change back to "Word"

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could accomplish this without any JavaScript. One option as noted before is to use CSS pseudo selectors and a content attribute.

However, this approach uses some trickery and it'd be better if your document included the content you wanted.

```
.wrap {
  margin: 30px auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 90vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.blue {
  background-color: rgba(56, 207, 248, 0.5);
}

.scale {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.box {
  width: calc(20%);
  margin: 20px 20px;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 130px;
}

.box:hover .scale {
  transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
}

.scale span {
  display: none;
}

.box:hover .scale span {
  display: inline;
}
```

https://codepen.io/eheisler/pen/bmMwre