# Change div content on mouse hover with default content fallback

Tags: javascript

I've implemented the accepted answer to [Change div content based on mouse hover on different divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097666/change-div-content-based-on-mouse-hover-on-different-divs?noredirect=1&lq=1) across a lot of links, so I don't really want to go with another solution if it can be avoided. I'm trying to figure out one more piece of the puzzle though...

I can't seem to get it to where it defaults back to the original text of the content div when not hovering over an item.

```
<div id="content">
    Stuff should be placed here.
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<ul>
    <li onmouseover="hover('Apples are delicious')">Apple</li>
    <li onmouseover="hover('oranges are healthy')">Orange</li>
    <li onmouseover="hover('Candy is the best')">Candy</li>
</ul>

<script>
    function hover(description) {
        console.log(description);
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = description;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the original text and bring it back when the mouse leaves.

```js
var element = getElementById('content'),
  storedText;

function hover(description) {
    console.log(description);
  storedText = element.innerHTML;
  element.innerHTML = description;
}

function leave() {
    element.innerHTML = storedText;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    Stuff should be placed here.
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<ul>
    <li onmouseover="hover('Apples are delicious')" onmouseleave="leave()">Apple</li>
    <li onmouseover="hover('oranges are healthy')" onmouseleave="leave()">Orange</li>
    <li onmouseover="hover('Candy is the best')" onmouseleave="leave()">Candy</li>
</ul>
```

It is generally recommended to add event listeners in the JS code and not in the HTML, but put that aside for now.

Comment: oops my JS isn't appearing

Comment: i guess you missed the leave() function

Comment: No I messed up the snippet syntax. Fixed now but the mouseover events still doesn't work for me. Wondering if it's because I'm on mobile or it's broken.

Comment: Ugh. I was so close at one point but before you fixed your js function snippet, I saw the onmouseleave in the html and got it done. Thank you so much! I can stop looking at that now. Need more coffee.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think in your code there was anything to make the content to go back to the default but i have made the least changes in your code to make the content to go back to default and i have used `onmouseout` event for that.

```
<div id="content">
    Stuff should be placed here.
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<ul>
    <li onmouseover="hover('Apples are delicious')" onmouseout="hover('Stuff should be placed here.')">Apple</li>
    <li onmouseover="hover('oranges are healthy')" onmouseout="hover('Stuff should be placed here.')">Orange</li>
    <li onmouseover="hover('Candy is the best')" onmouseout="hover('Stuff should be placed here.')">Candy</li>
</ul>

<script>
    function hover(description) {
        console.log(description);
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = description;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with Noam's answer simply because if I need to change the default text, I don't want to change every line.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same without any Javascript:

```css
li::before { content: attr(data-text); }
li:hover::before { content: attr(data-text-hover); }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li data-text-hover="Apples are delicious" data-text="Apple"></li>
    <li data-text-hover="Oranges are healthy" data-text="Orange"></li>
    <li data-text-hover="Candy is the best" data-text="Candy"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would have loved a pure CSS solution but because of the positioning and hierarchy of the div that needs to have the content changed (not inline), there were no CSS selectors to reach it from the li. I did try all variations of this first for this section because it's my goto whenever possible.